# Searching from a dataset still possess sql injection?

Tags: asp.net, sql-injection

If i have already got my data from the database into my dataset, and i want to search a name in my dataset, do i still have the risk of sql injection problem?
If yes, the way to remove it is through parameters only? or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

No, a `DataSet` or `DataTable` is not vulnerable to sql-injection since they are in-memory representations of your data.

So you should use parameters for the command that fills them, from then on you are safe.